# Hide div when there are no result due to a filter

Tags: angularjs

How can I know when there are no results to display due to a filter?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search...">

<div ng-show="contents.length !== 0">
  <h2>Contents</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="content in contents | filter:search">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{content.title}}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">{{content.description}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my solution working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VJr9o0H1subqC3jLa6eO?p=preview)

Simply using this do the trick.

```
 ng-show="(contents | filter:search).length !== 0"
```